# how can change the text string to date object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am getting string from server and i need to covert that fetching string in to new date object.. for doing this, i tried this function, but no use, any one can help me to convert strings to date object?

my code is :

```
var nationZone = {
        getNewYorkLocalTime :  'getTime.php?lat=40.71417&lan=74.00639',
        getLondonLocalTime : 'getTime.php?lat=51.5&lan=0.1166667',
        getChennaiLocalTime :  'getTime.php?lat=13.0833333&lan=80.2833333',
        getBangaloreLocalTime:'getTime.php?lat=12.9833333&lan=77.5833333'

    }

     $.each(nationZone , function(key, value){
        $.get(value, function(response){
            var newdate = $(response).find('localtime').text();
            if(key == "getNewYorkLocalTime"){
                var newyourktime = new Date(newdate);
                newyourktime.getTime()
            }
        });
    });
```

but, the newyourktime is showing local time only.. any help please? as well i am getting the response from server is : 17 Nov 2011 18:09:47 - like this.

Comment: Can you provide response from server?

Comment: response from server : 17 Nov 2011 18:09:47

Comment: How is `Date` supposed to magically know that you are passing it New York Local Time?

Comment: I dont know why people down vote this Question...

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.datejs.com/
As an example:

```
var newyourktime = Date.parse('2011-11-11, 11:11 AM');
alert(newyourktime.toString('dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss EST'));
```

Check out the Datejs library documentation to meet your requirements, after your date string is parsed, you can do a lot with it.

Answer (score 0):

This will try to parse the date using the client machine own local settings, which is not good.

Instead of passing it as string, pass it as the total seconds that passed since 1/1/1970 at midnight and use this number when constructing the new Date object of JavaScript.

For example pass this number: 1321614000000 and you will get November 18th 2011, 1 PM

Answer (score 0):

You could use substr

```
day = newdate.substr(0,2);
month = newdate.substr(3,3);
year = newdate.substr(7,4);
var newyorktime = new Date(year, month, day);
```

[Substr](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)